# How can I fetch items from different tables if there is foreign key available?

Tags: android, python

```
def select_info_project(droid, project_list):

    droid.dialogCreateAlert("Select Info Project")
    droid.dialogSetItems(project_list)
    droid.dialogShow()
    response = droid.dialogGetResponse().result

    #{u'item': 0}
    project = project_list[response['item']]

    return project
```

Now I want to retrieve items of selected project. How can I do this? i have items table also in which project id is a foreign key.

Comment: Do you mean a *database* foreign key or a key with non-ASCII characters?

Comment: actually i m using pyck framework.. now i have to write mobile code which is android programming in python..i've two models named class Info_projects(Base):
    __tablename__= 'info_projects'
    ip_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    ip_description=Column(UnicodeText)
    name=Column(Unicode(200),unique=True)

Comment: and 2nd table/model is  
class project_items(Base):
    __tablename__='project_items'
    pi_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    item_name=Column(Unicode(200))
    item_type=Column(Unicode(200))
    display_order=Column(Unicode(200))
    parent_item=Column(Unicode(200))
    infoproject_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Info_projects.ip_id))

Comment: and my file which is working fine is this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the application of python for android, but for python2.7 as I know it, you can pass a unicode key by adding a "u" in front of the unicode string...

```
  project = project_list[response[u'item']]
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more details about python and unicode.